# What is the difference between "are passed" and "have passed"?

Tags: present-perfect

What is the difference between following two answers:

1. I can confirm the results are passed.
2. I can confirm the results have passed.

The scenario was that a sample was submitted to the lab and the manager was asking the result.

I believe the meanings are same but I could be wrong. Please reply. Thanks.

Comment: Presumably, #2 is "reduced" from *...the results have passed **some relevant test***. By the same token, #1 should also be reduced, from something like *...the results **are passed** [the quality control test]*. But that's syntactic garbage.

Comment: The _results_ haven't passed - the sample has passed the test. The lab technician could say "The result was a pass" or "The sample has passed."

Comment: The first might be clearer as *I can confirm the results are "passed"*.

Answer (score 0):

What assessment, judgment, or requirement did the tests 'pass'?

Do you mean "I can confirm the test results all passed." meaning that you can confirm that the results of a group of tests met some criteria to be considered as a pass?

Another way might be: "I can confirm passing results for all tests."

'are passed' seems awkward and mixes current tense (are) and past tense (passed).

The second construction is valid English and would likely be interpreted as:

"I can confirm (all) the results have passed (some sort of criteria or standard)."